# MongoDb replaceOne() but wanted few field

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

in case of replaceOne() --> it replace whole object by new object -->what if i want few field of old object as it and replace that object by new object

Comment: Can you be more specific with example code that you tried. Try reading https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/mongoose-replaceone-1016

Answer (score 0):

replaceOne will replace the whole document and update with the one you are replacing you need to use updateOne instead this will only update specific fields which you wanted rest fields will be as it is

For example

```
 db.restaurant.updateOne(
      { "name" : "Central Perk Cafe" },
      { $set: { "violations" : 3 }},
      {upsert:true} 
   );
```

here upsert:true option will help in inserting new documents if it doesn't exist you can read more about it here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Answer (score 0):

you can use update
if you document is {name:"company",country:"India",owner:"me"}

```
db.company.update({
                  _id:*id*
                     },
                   {$set:{
                      name:"mycompany",
                      country:"United Kingdom"}})
```